# Express.js: Use Routers inside Routers

Tags: node.js, express

I have such router:

```
exports.read = (req,res) ->
  // do stuff with DB
  res.status(200).send
    data:data
```

Now how can I use this router inside another router, call it `exports.wrapper`? I wnat to avoid having to rewrite my DB requests again and again. Is this approach that I have in mind recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend attempting to wrap routers inside each other.

It's recommended in Express 4 to use Express's router object like so:

```
// router.js
var myRouter = express.Router();
myRouter.route('/read', myController.readMethod);
```

Then in your controller you would handle the request and end with the result call:

```
// myController.js
exports.readMethod = function(req, res) {
  var data = readFromDB(req.params);
  res.send('read method renders', data);
}

exports.readMethod2 = function(req, res) {
  var data = readFromDB(req.params);
  res.send('read method 2 renders', data);
}

function readFromDB(params) {
  // make a call to the DB (maybe via a model)
  // return some data
}
```

Hope that helps

**edit**
Additionally, I would recommend wrapping your DB calls in a model, to abstract them away from your router or controller logic. For a reference of a well organised Express App that uses MVC checkout this Yeoman generator - https://github.com/ngenerio/generator-express-simple

**second edit**
In my very brief example externalising the readFromDB method to a model makes this function moot, if all it's doing is getting data from the DB put it in a model.

Comment: How to re-use "exports.readMethod" in another method, lets say its called readMethod2?

Comment: If you want to call readMethod from the same module you can't you'd have to declare it as a function, I'll make an edit to my answer above

Comment: So it is not possible to re-use readMethod. I have the business logic inside of readMethod and do not want to repeat business logic twice, I am following DRY principles. Thus, I think I'll go what you suggested with readFromDB, put my logic into it, "OOP them" into coffee classes and `require` them into my controllers where I can re-use them as instances more than once.